# Restrict CPU/memory usage of geth while syncing

Tags: go-ethereum, memory, cpu

I'm trying to run a geth node and a bitcoin core node on one server. I started with a DigitalOcean droplet with 2 CPU and 2GB memory, but both the geth and bitcoin node would run out of memory. I upgraded it to 2 CPU and 4GB memory, but I notice that geth will take up 99% of the servers resources, no matter what configuration (unless maybe running a 16GB memory droplet, which is no option).

This results in the bitcoin node running out of memory and exiting.

Is there a way to ensure that geth only takes up max 50% cpu/memory? I don't want to split my setup to several nodes, increasing the complexity of my project's architecture.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For CPU try cpulimit, you will find guide [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-limit-cpu-usage-of-a-process-with-cpulimit-debian-ubuntu)
for RAM you can use ulimit, please refer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process)

PS. for my machine geth is resource hogging no matter what. Right now, it uses almost 10 GB of RAM, while system has 12 GB total. So I guess that's normal for eth.