# Memory usage and limits for go-ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, linux, memory, tuning

`geth` (and `swarm`) seem to require a lot of memory, and there are also reports that they tend to an [all you can eat](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/restrict-cpu-memory-usage-of-geth-while-syncing) approach to system limits.

1) What are the actual memory *requirements* for `geth`?

2) What is the best way to limit its usage? (`ulimit`, for example, uses `ENOMEM` as its gentlest approach which causes `out of memory` panics in `geth`, not very helpful)

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What are the actual memory requirements for geth?

It depends of the `--syncmode` of your node :
light < 380 MB (like btc, ltc, ...) but if you do that you will not have dag verification and not full contract suport so someone can make you fake coin by just creating a contract and say to you this contract add to your balance 2 ether, ... the 512mb on rinkeby ins't update
fast 1GB - 2GB
full 2GB - 4GB
archive 2GB - 8GB

src : https://www.rinkeby.io/#geth

> 2) What is the best way to limit its usage? (ulimit, for example, uses ENOENT which causes out of memory panics in geth, not very helpful)

the `--syncmode` `--cache` `--ethash.cache...` argv

PS : Go on the rinkeby web site (https://www.rinkeby.io/#geth) for see good preconfiguration (just remove all about rinkeby like `--networkid=4 --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --ethstats='yournode:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io' --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303?discport=30304`)

Comment: I'm not sure how this will help. For full node it says use `--cache=512` but default is `128` ... how can increasing this help limit usage? Also, the `--ethash.*` options' defaults together with this seem to define usage around 1.5Gb. So what accounts for the rest? These are just recipes, not explanations ;)

Comment: No, full node will use to much ram, use somethings like light node or somethings I call full light node (a full node but with ultra low memory usage) Here is my File :
`#!/bin/bash
cd /root/geth/
ip="$(ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet ad' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
nohup nice -n 10 ./geth -rpc -rpcaddr $ip --maxpeers 100000 --ipcdisable -rpcapi "admin,debug,eth,miner,net,personal,rpc,txpool,web3" -cache 256 --syncmode "full" --ethash.dagsondisk 4 --nat extip:<YOUR EXT IP> --ethash.dagsinmem 0 &` And my stop file :
`#!/bin/bash
pkill --signal 3 geth`